# Using parse.com is it possible to convert a string so that it saves as a pointer in the object browser?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript.

Currently I have a `BadgeSentTo` which is a string taken from a html option box. I want to save this to parse, but ideally I want to save it into a pointer column "SentTo" so that it links back to the _User class.

It wont let me save as is, because its expecting a pointer. Is there a why to convert this to a pointer in the code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#send").click(function () {

            var myBadge = new MyBadge();
            var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect img').attr("src");
            var BadgeSentTo = $('#SentToUser').val();

            var uploadercomment = $('#UploaderComment').val();
            myBadge.set("BadgeName", badgeselected); 
            myBadge.set("Comment", uploadercomment); 
            myBadge.set("uploadedBy", Parse.User.current());
            myBadge.set("SentTo", BadgeSentTo).id;


            myBadge.save(null, {
                success: function (results) {

                    console.log("Done");
                    //location.reload();
                },
                error: function (contact, error) {
                    // The save failed.

                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

The query capturing the data is

```
               var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
                var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

                var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
                query.include('toUser');
                query.include('SentTo');
                query.include("myBadge");
                query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
                query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");

                query.find({
                    success: function (results) {
                        var friends = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            friends.push({
                                username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                               userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                            });
                            var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
                            $.each(friends[0], function (i, v) {
                                //alert(i+" "+v);
                                var opt = v;
                                var el = document.createElement("option");
                                el.textContent = opt;
                                el.value = opt;
                                select.appendChild(el);
                            })

                        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If BadgeSentTo contains the objectId of the User, you'll need to wrap that in a Parse Object. The SDK will convert it to a pointer to `_User` when it saves.

```
myBadge.set("SentTo", new Parse.User({id: BadgeSentTo}));
```

Comment: Thanks,when I drop in that line I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" is there something else I'm overlooking?

Comment: Was missing a closing parenthesis